# How to open settings in single app mode on ipad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I am building an app for iPad. For this I need to restrict user access on iPad and allow the user to only access my app and the iPad settings.

So I've tried 2 approaches:

1. Used guided access to lock down my app and from within my app had a button that launches settings. This button doesn’t work if I run in guided mode. Without guided mode it works and the settings open up.

Question really is – How do I allow my app and settings to work in
Guided mode?

2. The same scenario as above, when I use Apple configurator to launch only one app so all others are restricted. I need to allow both my app and the iPad Settings to work and no other apps.

How do I do this?

Comment: Did you able to find solution for this? i have came across the same issue!!

Answer (score 1):

No you can't run more then one or multiple app in `guided access mode`. Because even if you want to press home button for going to background mode then also you need to `end guided access`. so, you can't open `setting app` from your app when `guided access` is enable for your app.

Only one app can run in `guided access` mode!

[Refer apple doc](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202612), it states,

- Temporarily restrict your iOS device to a single app
- Disable areas of the screen that aren’t relevant to a task, or areas
  where an accidental gesture might cause a distraction
- Disable the hardware buttons

Comment: Thanks Lion. Any idea if it's possible to do with apple configurator?

Comment: i don't have much idea about apple Configurator actually but i don't think so that this can be possible!!